# Dynamically changing the Data attribute value

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the data-tabtoggle attribute inside a div using my jq script. my code should change the value and then dynamically change the html. But nothing is happening : HTML

```
  <div id="Tab9" class="AllTabs JQApproval" data-tabtoggle="9" data-PlaceholderName = "Location"
         style="font-size:12px; " >Sales Approval
     <div id="Location"></div>
  </div>
```

my script

```
$('.JQApproval').click(
function() {

var ApprovalValue = $(this).attr('data-tabtoggle');

var PlaceHolder = $(this).attr('data-PlaceholderName') ; 
var NewApprovalValue 

if ( ApprovalValue === '9' ) { NewApprovalValue = '2' ; } ;
if ( ApprovalValue === '2' ) { NewApprovalValue = '1' } ;   
if ( ApprovalValue === '1' ) { NewApprovalValue = '9' } ;  

// Make new data attribute 
$('#Tab9').data('tabtoggle',20);

// test outcome 
$("#" + PlaceHolder ).html( NewApprovalValue ); 


});`
```

I need the HTML to reflect the changes but it does'nt

Any help would be appreciated !

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwl707/LdaLu4mb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try .attr() to set data-tabtoggle attribute:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fvmw6Lsc/

```
$('#Tab9').attr('data-tabtoggle',20);
```

Comment: Thanks but if you look at the HTML after the event , The data-tabtoggle value is still 9, I would expect it to be 20 ?

Comment: It works Dhara thank you. But I just wonder why the html does not update when viewed in google inspection page ?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually changing the number, but it's a text value so you must use quotes.

```
$('#Tab9').data('tabtoggle','20');
alert( $('#Tab9').data('tabtoggle') );
```

See revised Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/LdaLu4mb/8/

Comment: Thanks but if you look at the HTML after the event , The data-tabtoggle value is still 9, I would expect it to be 20 ?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot go by what you see in this case. The alert code gets the actual value of the current DOM state, and you can see that it alerts 20. :)  Channeling Richard Pryor: *Are you gonna trust me, or your own lyin' eyes?*